# Smooth Max and Abs

Tags: tensors, approximation

I'm trying to implement smooth approximations of Max and Abs functions. Moreover I want the functions to map element-wise on tensors. Here's my code.

```
$Assumptions = {
   Element[A, Arrays[{i, j, k}, Reals]],
   Element[Nlarge, Reals] (* Nlarge tends to infinity *)
   };
Hyper[x_] := Map[Exp[Nlarge #1] &, x, -1]
Hypo[x_] := Map[Log[#1]/Nlarge &, x, -1]
SMax[x__] := Hypo[Plus @@ (Map[Hyper, {x}])]
SAbs[x_] := SMax[x, -x]
SAbs[A] // TensorDimensions
```

I'm expecting it to return {i, j, k}, but instead I get {}. What's wrong with it?

Comment: Why do you expect it to return {i,j,k}?

Comment: I expect SAbs[A] to have the same dimensions as A, where each element in SAbs[A] approximates to Abs of the corresponding entry in A

Comment: This supposes that Exp[A] is a tensor, which it doesn't seem to be.

Comment: A is a symbolic array. In this case what would be the correct way to get element-wise Exp of a symbolic array?

Comment: I don't think there is any, but I'd be happy to be proven wrong. The symbolic tensor stuff works by using specific `Assumptions`. I don't think `Exp` has been updated to work with those.